# How to use hdfs shell commands with apache zeppelin?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, apache-zeppelin

I have installed apache zeppelin by downloading and extracting the [binary with all interpreters](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/install/install.html#package-with-all-interpreters)

I then started it up with:

```
./bin/zeppelin.sh start
```

I then created a new notebook with the following code:

```
%sh

hdfs fs -ls
```

When I run it I get the I get as a result:

```
bash: hdfs: command not found
ExitValue: 127
```

isn't zeppelin supposed to come with [hdfs interpreter](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/interpreter/hdfs.html) or support `hdfs` commands?

If zeppelin does not include `hdfs` file system then I started up: 
 https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hadoop-spark-workbench

Then started it up with docker-compose up . I navigated to the various urls mentioned in the git readme and all appears to be up.  Which I think means I have some hdfs is up but i'm not sure whether I should have done that or the "all" interpreters package from zeppelin already includes it, in anyway i got the same result either way.

My end goal is simply local playground of `hdfs` together with `spark` with the help of `zeppelin`.

How am I supposed to run `hdfs` commands such as `hdfs fs -ls` with a local installation of apache zeppelin that includes [all interpreters](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/install/install.html#package-with-all-interpreters)? Does it include `hdfs` and `hdfs` commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does but you are using shell interpreter.

Make sure that `file` interpreter is installed:

```sh
$ ./bin/install-interpreter.sh --list | grep file
## file         HDFS file interpreter
```

If not install it

```
$ ./bin/install-interpreter.sh --name file
```

Add `file` interpreter to the notebook and use it

```
%file

ls /
```

To use `hadoop fs` commands you need Hadoop installation (Hadoop binaries and correct configuration and environment variables):

```
%sh

$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -ls /
```

You will need one for more complex tasks, as HDFS interpreter (a.k.a. `file` interpreter)

> currently only supports browsing.

Comment: It sounds more serious than it is - download binaries, edit configuration, set `HADOOP_HOME` and `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` (in `zeppelin-env.sh` will do fine) and you should be set.  Or just use HDFS client directly in your code. _I also don't see any documentation for the "file" interpreter_ - `file` interpreter is HDFS interpreter. Unfortunate choice of name I guess.